# How to Authenticate With Password and write text to nfc in android

Tags: android, nfc

Hi im developing simple NFC App.While reading i should authenticate with
      password and then resume the write something to NFC tag.Also i should 
      authenticate with the same password to read the data means Ndef message 
      from the tag.Reading the tag and writing the tag done.But im stuck in with      writing to tag with password authentication.Here is the code i done for password 
        authentication.Using MifareUltralight i want to authenticate i read from
        authentication i need to transceive the command with 0x1B. But no idea how 
       to approach this task. Im beginner to this NFC tech.Please help me out 
       from this i spent more days on it.Please somebody help me out.

```
       MifareUltralight ptag = MifareUltralight.get(detectedTag);
    String password = "HELL";
    String resultString = "";
    byte[] array = password.getBytes();
    // byte[] pwd = new byte[] { (byte)0x70, (byte)0x61, (byte)0x73, (byte)0x73 };
    byte[] pack = new byte[]{(byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x76};



    try {

        try {
            ptag.connect();

            result = ptag.transceive(new byte[]{
                    (byte) 0xA2,  //* CMD = WRITE *//*
                    (byte) 0x2C,  //* PAGE = 44 *//*
                    pack[0], pack[1], 0, 0
            });
            result = ptag.transceive(new byte[]{
                    (byte) 0xA2,  //* CMD = WRITE *//*
                    (byte) 0x2B, //* PAGE = 43 *//*
                    array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]


            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("pack protected", "pckkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk" + "\n" + (char) pack[0] + "\n" + (char) pack[1]);

        Log.e("password protected", "pwd" + "\n" + (char) array[0] + "\n" + (char) array[1] + "\n" + (char) array[2] + "\n" + (char) array[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should know which version of Mifare Ultralight you are using. There are basically Mifare Ultralight, Ultralight C and Ultralight EV1. All of them have different security features.[NXP product page](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification-and-security/smart-card-ics/mifare-ics/mifare-ultralight:MC_53452?cof=0&am=0&tab=Products)
The Ev1 has a 32-bit password feature for write or read/write protection.
For details how to authenticate with the password you have to take a look into the datasheet at chapter 10.8.[Mifare Ultralight Ev1 datasheet](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF0ULX1.pdf?pspll=1)

You have to send the CMD+password which is in your case 0x1B+'H'+'E'+'L'+'L'

Comment: Rather than posting where to find the answer (in the link), you're supposed to distill that information to suit this question.  Please see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) and [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing) for some guidelines.  Link-only answers are considered low quality answers on StackOverflow, and are subject to deletion.

Comment: i tried this result = ptag.transceive(new byte[]{
                        (byte) 0x1B,
                        array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],
                }); i'm getting  exception android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.

Comment: Do you know which tag tpe you exactly use? THis is important because the authenticate works only with Mifare UL EV1 tags!

Comment: MifareUltralight NTAG213,Type 2 tag

Comment: Do you have written the password before? Check out the datasheet [link](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf)You have to write the password to the dedicated address.

Comment: String password = "HELL";
    String packass="EL";

Comment: MifareUltralight  ptag=MifareUltralight.get(detectedTag);

        passack=packass.getBytes();
        array = password.getBytes();

Comment: try {
            ptag.connect();
            result = ptag.transceive(new byte[]{
                    (byte) 0xA2,  /* CMD = WRITE */
                    (byte) 44,  /* PAGE = 44 */
                    passack[0], passack[1],
                    (byte) 0, (byte) 0
            });
            Log.e("pack protected", "pckkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk" + "\n" + (char) passack[0] + "\n" + (char) passack[1]);

Comment: result = ptag.transceive(new byte[]{
                    (byte) 0xA2,  /* CMD = WRITE */
                    (byte) 43,  /* PAGE = 43 */
                    array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3]


            });
            Log.e("password protected", "pwd" + "\n" + (char) array[0] + "\n" + (char) array[1] + "\n" + (char) array[2] + "\n" + (char) array[3]);

Comment: hi i'm setting the desired password programatically which i posted above

Comment: can u pls explain how to set password and also remove it? and how ?